# Spark-Scala HBase table creation fails (MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/src is not a directory or unable to create one)

Tags: scala, hadoop, hbase, apache-spark, pyspark

I have hortonworks sandbox running in my VM. I have done all the hive-site.xml configurations and placed in Spark/conf file.

I can access HBase using PySpark and create/update tables but when I do the same implementation in scala its giving me the following error:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/src is not a directory
>   or unable to create one)

I have changed my permission on ‘hive/warehouse’ folder too but still its giving me the same error.

```
[root@sandbox ~]# sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -ls -d /user/hive/warehouse
drwxrwxrwt   - hdfs hdfs          0 2015-02-02 09:19 /user/hive/warehouse
```

My hive-site.xml contains following property

```
<property>
      <name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
      <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
      <value>hive</value>
</property>
<property>
      <name>java.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
      <value>hive</value>
      <description>
      </description>
 </property>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the mistake I was making.

The correct **SPARK_HOME** location must be specified in the code that runs on the local machine

```
import os
import sys

# Path for spark source folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="/Users/renienj/spark-1.1.0/dist"
```

Basically, the local machine doesn’t have privileges to HDFS because the classpath does not include **HADOOP_CONF_DIR**. Hence, the **warehouse** and **tmp** directories are in Hadoop but the table directory creation failures are stored in the local file system.

So to solve the problem we need submit the packaged JAR with the local distribution package.

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class "Hello" --master local[4] hello-scala_2.10-1.0.jar
```